# Maxwell and Newton

Tags: electromagnetism, maxwell-equations, galilean-relativity

Has anyone tried to modify Maxwell's electromagnetic field theory so that it is invariant under the Galilean transformation?

Comment: Make a Galilean transformation in the equations, and subtract the new terms. This way the "new" Maxwell equations will be invariant under it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Galilean invariance of a subset of Maxwell equations](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79710/)

Comment: What would be the point of that, given that we know that Galilean transformations aren’t the correct transformations between inertial reference frames?

Comment: The answer seems to be Galilean electrodynamics. See the journal Galilean Electrodynamics and the Wikipedia article on Galilean electromagnetism (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galilean_electromagnetism).